# Expedition 53 group portrait - what's up with the cool shirts?

Tags: iss, space-art

The image is from NASA Media Advisory M17-124 [Georgia Students to Speak with NASA Astronauts on Space Station](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/georgia-students-to-speak-with-nasa-astronauts-on-space-station) but there is no mention of the cool shirts.

---

**below:** *The six Expedition 53 crew members gather together in the Destiny laboratory module for a group portrait. From left are astronauts Joe Acaba, Paolo Nespoli, and Mark Vande Hei, Commander Randy Bresnik and cosmonauts Sergey Ryazanskiy and Alexander Misurkin. On Monday, Acaba, Vande Hei and Bresnik will speak with students from New Prospect Elementary School in Alpharetta, Georgia*. Credits: NASA

[image]

**below:** Cropped detail of same image.

[image]

Comment: Something about "the island lifestyle" , see https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/michigan-students-to-speak-with-nasa-astronauts-on-space-station . The island is Hawaii, I think. Very special kind of Hawaii shirt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Randy Bresnik tweeted about it! Practicing 'Aloha Friday' wearing space themed Aloha Shirts at work.

> Our Earth is but an island in the cosmos. Exp 53 crew is embracing the island lifestyle with our @Space_Station Hawaiians on #Aloha Friday!

https://twitter.com/AstroKomrade/status/911191244469977089

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_shirt#Aloha_Friday

Comment: It wasn't uncommon to see Hawaiian shirts on Fridays around Mission Operations Directorate at JSC. Seemed more popular in the late 90s/early 00s.